# Analyse and predict engine malfunction origin from audio

Tags: android, signal-processing, data-analysis

I had an idea to build an app which a user would input audio from the mic of the phone and through proper analysis of the input sound, make suggestive areas of the engine which might need repair. Can someone guide and breakdown the processes I need to do to build it from scratch up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-topic, but as a person who understands a little more than nothing in cars and engines I can tell you this is mostly useless. A perfectly working old engine will sound totally different from a new engine, same engine runs differently based on outside temperature, fans working will also interfere with your so called diagnosis, same-frequency vibration of body panels and other plastic pieces will join the orchestra, a failing tensioner/pulley can easily be mistaken for a failing injector or hydraulic tappet and so on

you'd need a massive amount of real life data with each engine type/variation/age and failed component, and you still wouldn't be able to give more than a 5-15% precise description.

tldr: drop it

Comment: Any way we can reduce the factors which can cause interference in the problem detection or introduce another source of stimuli in addition to the audio to provide a more concrete level of diagnosis?

Comment: theoretically yes, but in real life this wouldn't work. Modern engines are full of sensors (flow, pressure, mixture, temperature) that already do a great job in reporting it's status through the diagnostic port (by modern I mean last 15-20 years - which makes 95% of all the cars alive) while manufacturers are trying to force replacement over repairing for obvious reasons, and while you would be able to diagnose the failing pulley mentioned above, that's a fairly easy task for most mechanics. I've seen many of them use stethoscopes to listen to one spot at a time in case they're not sure

Comment: Appreciate your wisdom. :)